# Redirect jQuery Mobile page on form submit in Trigger.io

Tags: jquery-mobile, trigger.io

I'm trying to build a simple prototype of an app and I cannot seem to get JQM to change to either an internal or external page with `$.mobile.changePage($('#page2'))` or `$.mobile.changePage('page2.html')`.

I have successfully binded the form submit to the button, but when clicking (tapping), it changes the same page. After a second click/tap, it redirects.

```
$("#fd-login button#login-fd-submit").on('click', function(e) {
  forge.logging.info('login-fd-submit clicked');
  $.mobile.changePage('page2.html');
});
```

Comment: Did you try just using the 'tap' event instead of 'click'?

Comment: @KrisKrause Using `$(element).live('tap', function() {});` works best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:-

```
 $("#fd-login button#login-fd-submit").on('tap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    forge.logging.info('login-fd-submit clicked');
    $.mobile.changePage('page2.html');
 });
```

Update: Changed to use tap event.

Comment: That didn't work either. In the Trigger console:   
First Click: [INFO] Loading local url in webview: file://forge-assets/src/index.html#cases

Second Click: [INFO] Loading local url in webview: file://forge-assets/src/index.html#/src/index.html

Edit: Shift + Enter *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$(element).on("click", function() {});` doesn't work for this. `$(element).live("click", function() {});` works perfectly.

Comment: Okay.  So its NOT a trigger.io issue?

Comment: which jquery version u r using ?

Comment: @KrisKrause: It wasn't a trigger.io issue from what I could tell. I had this issue creating a different app outside of trigger.io and decided to try it.

Comment: @SJGJ: jQuery: 1.7.1 JQM: 1.1.0 (going to update it to the latest soon)

Answer (score 0):

For a "local" page in your "src" directory:

```
$("#fd-login button#login-fd-submit").on('click', function(e) {
    forge.logging.info('login-fd-submit clicked');

    forge.file.getLocal('page2.html', function(file) {
       $.mobile.changePage(file);
    }, function(err) { 
       forge.logging.log("error");
    });
});
```

If you are using a jQuery object instead, then its mostly likely **not** trigger.io and need to see more code.